# Add a treadmill and refrigerator to the wall outlet in my garage without tripping any circuit breakers?

Tags: electrical, switch, electrical-panel

I rent a house in the US and recently have decided I’d like to add a refrigerator and exercise treadmill to my garage. The washer and dryer are already plugged into a receptacle in the garage  so I was hoping that the new additions could plug into a second receptacle.

I don’t want to trip any breakers with all these new appliances, especially if they were all to run at the same time  so I tried to figure out if the washer/dryer are on their own dedicated circuit, as well as which circuit powers the receptacle I’d like to use for the new additions.

I’m green when it comes to this sort of stuff. In my panel box there’s a circuit labeled “washer/dryer”  but flipping it off does not power off *anything* in the house. I’ve tried the other breakers  and combinations of them  but nothing seems to power off the washer/dryer or the other garage receptacle.
The *ONLY* thing that works is flipping off the 100amp double pole breaker, which shuts off *everything* in the house as well.

What’s going on here?

Can I safely assume that adding a treadmill and fridge to the garage won’t create excessive electrical load, since they are seemingly on a 100 amp breaker?

(*I feel like I’m missing something here*)

[image: panel breaker]

Comment: Try shutting all the breakers off at the same time except for the 100 Amp breaker.  It's not uncommon for the labeling on the panel to be all wrong.  Then check the garage for power.

Comment: Have you tried turning off all of the breakers (other than the main) at the same time or just one by one?

Comment: Any other breakers on that meter center??

Comment: Thanks, I can’t at the moment but I’ll give that a shot in a few hours. But what would that tell me? That I missed some combination?

Comment: And no, these are all the breakers

Comment: Is there any chance there's a subpanel in the garage? Can you take a picture of the washer/dryer receptacles? And btw, 13 and 14 should probably be tied together at the handles.

Comment: Can you post a photo of any labeling on the inside of the meter-center's door?  Also, it sounds like you need to go on a subpanel scavenger hunt, because *clearly* this can't be the only panel in the house...

Comment: You mention that you rent. Electrical work is usually done by licensed electricians with landlord approval on rental properties per local ordinances. The “work allowed to be done directly by homeowner” clauses usually don’t  apply because you are a renter and the homeowner... well nobody wants slumlords who hack together unsafe electrical solutions instead of calling in a licensed electrician to make sure its done properly. In either case, is your landlord cool with you doing the work?

Comment: Presumably a gas dryer? If not, there almost has to be a sub-panel someplace, unless it's connected to 13-14 (which are not handle-tied, and should be, but not by you) instead of the very faded "A/C"

Comment: Consider this: NEC 210.11(C)(2) Laundry Branch Circuits. In addition to the number of branch circuits required by other parts of this section, at least
one additional 20-ampere branch circuit shall be provided to
supply the laundry receptacle outlet(s) required by 210.52(F).
This circuit shall have no other outlets.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses!

I flipped off all the breakers except for the 100 Amp, and that shut off the washer and dryer! I then flipped back on each breaker, one at a time, and checked what turned on. 
Pretty much everything is labeled incorrectly...and I'm confused as to why certain things are on the same circuit. It seems that the washer/dryer run on the same circuit as the bathroom lights (share a wall), as well as the outlets in 3 bedrooms that we happen to use for our PCs.

On  the other hand, the 2nd receptacle in the garage is on the same circuit as the bedroom lights...

Comment: I've also searched inside and outside the house, and there doesn't seem to be any sort of subpanel. 

And as for doing any electrical work, I have no knowledge of how to even attempt it, nor would I risk damaging part of the house or injuring myself and others. I'm simply trying to understand the implications of plugging in other objects into the outlets!

Answer (score 1):

As a **renter**, your "work" can only consist of trying to track down what the actual relationship of circuits to locations is (see if there's another spot that "looks like" it could have had a washer/dryer, for instance) and trying the devices you want to run on the outlets you want to run them on to see if a breaker trips, or not - given that modern refrigerators are usually small loads (mine does 50-60W unless it's defrosting at 200W) your main likely issue with overloading would be don't wash **and** dry **and** treadmill at the same time.

We have some previous questions and answers about tracking down circuits. Labelling is often outdated or wrong - just be systematic and make a note of what breaker affects each device location.

Any electrical *work* on a rental **has** to be done by a licensed electrician (as others already commented.)

Comment: Circuit mapping: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/36917/18078

Comment: Thank you for the response! I definitely am not going to be doing any electrical work on this house, nor do I have the knowhow to even attempt. As you stated, I'm purely just trying to understand the layout of the circuits and the implications of adding more electrically operated objects (treadmill, fridge, etc.)

As for refrigerator loads, I understand that their running loads are low, like you stated, but how about their "starting loads"? A quick google search is showing me numbers in the 1000-2000W range